# Evaluate Boolean Expression in Java with variables stored in a List

Tags: java, boolean, double, expression, evaluation

i am looking for an easy to evaluate a String as a boolean expression containing double and boolean values.

```
(exposeOk && (creditPoints >= 114.5)) || stateAchieved
```

I already had a look at [javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/) but i am not sure, if it supports multiple dataTypes like double and boolean in one expression?!

The biggest challenge is, that the variable values are not stored e.g. in a variable called "exposeOk" but in a list with objects containing string-value-pairs. So if the evaluator needs the value for exposeOk it has to search the List for objects containing the string "exposeOk" and has to use the value stored in that object.

I hope someone can help me with this challenge ;-)

Comment: sounds unclear to me, can you detail a little more and provide some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use EL 3.0, now available in standalone mode

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.el.ELProcessor;

    public class ExpressionLanguageExample {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
            variables.put("exposeOk", true);
            variables.put("creditPoints", 220.2);
            variables.put("stateAchieved", true);

            ELProcessor elProcessor = new ELProcessor();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entrySet : variables.entrySet()) {
                String key = entrySet.getKey();
                Object value = entrySet.getValue();
                elProcessor.setValue(key, value);
            }
            Object eval = elProcessor.eval("(exposeOk && (creditPoints >= 114.5)) || stateAchieved");
            System.out.println(eval);
        }
    }
```

Some links:

http://www.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/whats-new-with-expression-language-in-java-ee-7
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_hidden_javaee_7_gem

Comment: Came to recommend an EL (SpEL in my case, but vanilla EL is probably fine for the OP).

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. First i thought the problem would be to, that i would have to detect the variables that are used in the expression and load these from the list into the ELProcessor. But i just had the idea of just loading all variables from the list to the processor and accept the tiny performance loss.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the format of your expression. Java and javascript expressions are similar. If that syntax works then you could use the built-in javascript engine to process your expression.

First loop over your collection of key/values and build them into a string separated with a semicolon. Then append the expression and call the engine.

The code below just shows the mechanics. You'll still have a lot of error checking to do.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Expr {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ScriptException {

        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        // Get your variables into javascript code
        String vars = "exposeOk=true;creditPoints=120.5;stateAchieved=false";

        // The expression
        String expr = "(exposeOk && (creditPoints >= 114.5)) || stateAchieved";

        String t = engine.eval(vars+";"+expr).toString();

        System.out.println(t); // Prints "true"

    }

}
```